# Trying to upload nltk in python to heroku for web app but it is not uploading

Tags: python, web, heroku, nltk, streamlit

I am new to heroku and I am trying to deploy a python streamlit file. I am facing difficulty in `nltk.txt` file. I have mentioned nltk in `requirements.txt`.
These are the nltk packages I am using. I would really appreciate the help in defining them in the nltk.txt file

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
```

I have mentioned these in the nltk.txt file

```
stopwords
wordnet
pros_cons
reuters
hmm_treebank_pos_tagger
maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
universal_tagset
punkt
averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru
averaged_perceptron_tagger
snowball_data
rslp
porter_test
vader_lexicon
treebank
dependency_treebank
```

But when I do this, I get this error

```
Error loading hmm_treebank_pos_tagger: Package
remote: [nltk_data]     'hmm_treebank_pos_tagger' not found in index
remote: Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
```

I would really appreciate the help
Thank You

Comment: Looks like an nltk issue. Have you tried [this] (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/444)

Comment: @Linju I tried but couldn't get a fix to my issue

Comment: What did you do exactly and what is the new error message?

Comment: I removed ```hmm_treebank_pos_tagger``` from the txt file and it ran with giving any error. But when I type ```heroku open```, it opens the browser and says it cannot run it